# What API should I use to write network usage program?

Tags: c++, windows, api, network-programming

I found my computer was using a lot of network bandwidth and I want to figure out which program is actually doing this in the background.

I did some research and I could not find any free software having the capability of recording the network usage of each the program; so I want to write a simple one myself.

I want to write it in C++ but I have no idea which API I can use.

Can you suggest any?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what APIs to use but TCPView does what I think you want: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

Comment: @James hmmm, this works. I think I need to improve my research skill then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), and/or [netstat](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: I tried netstat but it could not tell me the network usage of each program